# Is it possible to apply a Kalman filter to a 2D thermal problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab, heat-equation, kalman-filter

I have a transient thermal problem: I've created a 2D geometry with two different materials, I've put in an internal source, I've mashed it and solved the PDE. After a t time I can see how the structure diffuses the heat. I've taken different temperature points and I've put in a random noise to create something similar to a real case. Now I would like to apply a Kalman filter to get an estimate of my system but I think it's not the right filter to apply to a thermal problem. The equation of my problem it's the heat equation.